# What to call a family you make yourself?

Tags: word-choice

What do you call a family you create yourself through marriage or having children?

I want to distinguish between the family I was born into (my birth family) versus the one I made.

Comment: There isn't a specific term. You can either refer to "starting a family", or use "my wife/husband and children."

Comment: The term *nuclear family* is used to describe a simple family of parents and their children - as opposed to *extended family* which encompasses grandparents, aunts, uncles, cousins etc. Though the term *nuclear family* could equally apply to one's birth family, I tend to use the expression *my own nuclear family* if I wish to make it clear that I am speaking about my children plus my wife and myself only.

Comment: Wow, do you think I'll end up on even more government lists if I use that term a lot? I worry about that kind of thing a lot, but I probably shouldn't.

Comment: You will if you refer to your children as the "aliens". ;-)

Comment: That is definitely getting too close to black helicopter territory!

Comment: @ThomBlairIII Er, what? Because it has the word "nuclear" in it?

Comment: Yep. I tend try to avoid words that might "trigger" the government, like there are certain four-letter words you never say in an airport. So, I kinda feel like the 7-letter n word is one in pseudo-close territory to such triggering language. But hopefully their filters get some human attention before they send the black sedans for you. XD

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Ah! Yes, that's a dupe. I didn't see it before I asked. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomBlairIII It's alright, I didn't see it before I answered.

Answer (score 5):

You might call it your **household**:

> The inhabitants of a house considered collectively; a group of people (esp. a family) living together as a unit; a domestic establishment (including any servants, attendants, etc.).

([Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/88908?redirectedFrom=household#eid))

However, this of course presumes that your family is not separated. It does sound a little archaic though, but saying something like:

> The rest of my family is very conservative but my **household** is quite liberal.

The definition states it includes servants, but I wouldn't jump to this understanding as an American, it might be different in other countries or social levels.

---

There's also **family unit**:

> n. a family considered as a single entity, esp. as a discrete constituent of society; the primary social group, traditionally consisting of parents and their children.

([OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/67975?redirectedFrom=family%20unit#eid278234765))

But this sounds almost statistical in nature to me, I would be hard-pressed to use it naturally in conversation.

Comment: You need to be careful. A household can also include servants.

Comment: Bear in mind that *household* would also include your resident servants, pets etc. One of the prophets in the Old Testament is recorded as having several thousand in his "household" - most of them probably slaves.

Comment: @Mick Ah yes, I forgot to talk about that. I don't think many people would understand "household" that way, but maybe I'm just not rich enough.

Comment: @WS2 See my comment about servants. and re: pets, I think it would be clear from context whether you're discussing just humans or also pets.